# Junit testing android across multiple configurations (portrait & landscape)

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, robotium

I am just starting to use `Robotium` & `Junit` to test an android app.

I want to write a test once and then have that exact same test run twice... once in portrait and once in landscape.

I am used to `Nunit/C#` with test case attributes like this:

```
[TestCase(12,3,4)]
[TestCase(12,2,6)]
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
  Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

Is there something like that I can do in `Eclipse` with `Java/Robotium`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using Robotium and Java. What you would do is create two test methods. You have to begin them with "test", so in your case it would be testDivideTest1() and testDivideTest2()... Once you create the methods, you will use the `setActivityOrientation(int orientation)` method at the beginning of your test. So your test might look something like this:

```
TestCase(12,3,4)]
[TestCase(12,2,6)]
[TestCase(12,4,3)]

...(Set up methods)...
public void testDivideTest1(int n, int d, int q)
{
  setActivityOrientation(portrait);
  Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

Test two:

```
TestCase(12,3,4)]
[TestCase(12,2,6)]
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
...(Set up methods)...
public void testDivideTest2(int n, int d, int q)
{
  setActivityOrientation(landscape);
  Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

Hope that helps. Here is a reference link: http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers

This link has the link to download the javadoc which has all the needed methods. When you download the javadoc, it will a .jar file, so just change the .jar to .zip and you will be able to access it.